# term frequency using java program

Tags: java

I have set of documents. I want to know the frequency count of each word in each document (i.e) term frequency using java program. thanks in advance. I know how to find the frequency count for each word. My question is about how to take the unique words in each document from the list of documents

Comment: What format are your documents in?

Answer (score 2):

You can split your documents on spaces and punctuation, go through the resulting array and then count frequency for each word (a `Map<String, Integer>` would really help you with this).

---

**Resources :**

- [Java - faster data structure to count word frequency?](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t142017-faster-data-structure-to-count-word-frequency.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [How to count words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983586/how-to-count-words-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

If it's more than a one time problem to solve, you should consider using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) to index your documents. Then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249364/in-a-lucene-lucene-net-search-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-hits-per-document) would help you answer your question.