# identify the frequency count using java

Tags: java

I need to identify the frequency count for the particular list. My list will look like

```
gun,bun 
bun,gun,
pin,bin
bin,pin
stay,way.
```

From the above list, i need the output as

```
gun,bun  2
pin,bin  2
stay,way 1
```

Suggest any ideas please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [term frequency using java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647153/term-frequency-using-java-program)

Comment: @Bart Kiers: The recent edit seems to change the intent of the OP. He just wants the count of individual words. After the edit, you might think that it is order-insensitive pair count.

Comment: @Ravi, you probably meant to reply to someone else?

Comment: @Bart I see you as the last editor, so I guessed that you formatted the question to make it look a bit neater. Either way, since you have the privileges to edit the question, I thought it would be just fine.

Comment: @Ravi, yes I removed the "asap" remark, but I can still (politely) ask the OP to omit such things for the next time s/he asks a question, no?

Comment: @Bart We aren't talking about the same thing ;). I didn't comment about the ASAP part. Original question didn't have the input and output formatted as code. But later someone formatted them to look as code. Looking at it seem to suggest that the OP wants pair wise count than individual count. [{gun,pun},{pin,bin},{stay,way}]

Comment: @Ravi, ok, ahh, I see what you mean :). I simply indented the OP's post a bit: s/he posted the original input and output on separate lines but the forum software ignores such single line breaks. If I edited incorrect, I guess the OP can edit that part back.

Answer (score 2):

```
//this is data string
String str = "gun,bun,bun,gun,pin,bin bin,pin,stay,way";
// here we have created a map with String key and Integer values
Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
//now we are iterating through each string by splitting data by "," so we'll get each string
for (String strTmp : str.split(",")) {
        //checking if map already contains the entry then update the count
        if (hm.containsKey(strTmp)) {
               Integer val = hm.get(strTmp);
               val = val + 1;
               hm.put(strTmp, val);
        } else {//else just add it
               hm.put(strTmp, 1);
        }
}
//printing the result
System.out.println(hm);
```

Comment: The down-vote was mine: I often do that when people simply post a spoon-feed solution without any comments or explanation. I smells a bit like rep-hunting. Note that I'll gladly remove it if you (IMO) improve your answer. And it doesn't even work properly... :)

Comment: -1 this doesn't work. Your code outputs "{bun bun=1, pin stay=1, bin bin=1,  pin=1, way=1, gun=2}" which doesn't match the OP's output.

Comment: @Bart thanks for pointing it out. I didn't realize this. I have added info here. @dogbane I am not here to *format OP's output* the only thing is how to implement it, thats what OP needs. and OP will let me know it, if s/he will need help for this. you are **not at all appreciated** to downvote.

Comment: @jigar-joshi-org-life-java I'm not talking about formatting. Look at the **contents** of your hashmap. Do they match the OP's output? It's completely wrong.

Comment: @dogbane ah.. it was about that missing comma in data string. I reverted. If this was the only your problem I hope you will revert your downvote

Comment: @jigar-joshi-org-life-java it's still wrong. I believe the OP wants to count the frequency of **pairs** of words, not of single words. E.g. gun,bun is one pair and it's output should be 2.

Comment: @dogbane OP has just kept these word together , the final output he has grouped with no of occurance.

Answer (score 2):

You should also take a look at the [google guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), specifically the [Iterables](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) frequency method

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashMap<String,Integer>`, loop through the list of words and store the count . Refer to the documentation here on how to use `HashMap`:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of words for each row and use method Collection.containsAll(...) to check if rows contain same set of words.

Answer (score 0):

Commons Collection provides a "Bag", that behaves as desired. http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html
There also exists a more recent implemenation on sourceforge that can handle generics https://sourceforge.net/projects/collections/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.frequency()` method to count frequency. You are passing string which is comma seperated so we need to create object of such String given below. Create a class and pass your string object(comma seperated String object) and override `equals` and `hashcode` method to identify both strings are equals.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CommaSeperatedStringObject> list = new ArrayList<CommaSeperatedStringObject>();
        list.add(new CommaSeperatedStringObject("gun,bun"));
        list.add(new CommaSeperatedStringObject("bun,gun"));
        list.add(new CommaSeperatedStringObject("dan,dana,dan"));
        list.add(new CommaSeperatedStringObject("pin,bin"));
        list.add(new CommaSeperatedStringObject("dana,dan,dan"));
        list.add(new CommaSeperatedStringObject("bin,pin"));
        list.add(new CommaSeperatedStringObject("stay,way"));
        list.add(new CommaSeperatedStringObject("dan,dan,dana"));
        Map<CommaSeperatedStringObject, Integer> map = new HashMap<CommaSeperatedStringObject, Integer>();
        for (CommaSeperatedStringObject s : list) {
            map.put(s, Collections.frequency(list, s)); // here you can check frequency.
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}

class CommaSeperatedStringObject {
    String str1;
    List<String> strList;
    public CommaSeperatedStringObject(String str) {
        this.str1 = str;
        String[] seperate = str1.split(",");
        strList = Arrays.asList(seperate);
        Collections.sort(strList);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        CommaSeperatedStringObject cso = (CommaSeperatedStringObject)obj;
        boolean status = false;
        if(this.strList.equals(cso.strList)){
            status = true;
        }
        return status;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n"+strList.toString();
    }
}
```