# query processing

Tags: java

lets say i type in question : Where are you ?

the program will process 'you' and calculate the term frequency of the word 'you'.

How to process the query 'where are you' ?

Comment: Please try to clarify or rephrase your question. It's unclear what you're asking. For example: why should the program pick out "you"? Why doesn't it "process 'are' and calculate the term frequency of the word 'are'"?

Comment: Is `?` considered a 'word' here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

- [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
- [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)
- [`split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
- [identify-the-frequency-count-using-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116630/identify-the-frequency-count-using-java/5116690#5116690)